# Aptana Studio: Creation Problems 'Resource already exists'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana, aptana3

Ok so i had a project that i wanted to completely restart, so i deleted the folder in my workspace directory (in finder). Now when i have recreated the ruby project(it has the same name) and i go to Aptana and "import" a folder as my project, it says cannot create since      `'Resource /NameOfProject already exists'`.

I've tried deleting the metadata and DS_Store files as well, i've tried using a different workspace and then importing the project over, still the same problem, any idea what's going on?

TIA

Comment: Is the project still showing in the Project Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Project explorer > Right click the folder > Delete.

Now you should be able to import the folder.

Comment: i thought i had the project explorer open x_x